# Spring resolver not being hit when I set the mappedEndpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

The resolvers `customizeFault` method isnt being hit when I set the mapped endpoints below.  If I remove it, it gets hit.  Any help?  The exception is thrown in my resolver class.

**MembershipManagementEndpoint.java**

```
package com.openclass.adapter.ws;

@Endpoint
public class MembershipManagementEndpoint {
```

**Spring Config**

```
<bean id="membershipExceptionResolver" class="com.openclass.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisMembershipResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="1"></property>
        <property name="mappedEndpoints">
            <set>
                <value>com.openclass.adapter.ws.MembershipManagementEndpoint</value>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver.java**

```
    package com.openclass.adapter.ws.resolvers;
    public class LisMembershipResolverInterceptor extends LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver {

@Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
            throws Exception {

            throw new LisMembershipException();

        return true;
    }
```

**LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver.java**

```
public abstract class LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver extends
        SimpleSoapExceptionResolver implements SoapEndpointInterceptor {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add to build separate interceptor/resolver for each endpoint and then test in the interceptor/resolver and test for the correct endpoint.

**SoapFaultExceptionResolver**

```
  @Override
    protected final boolean resolveExceptionInternal(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) {

        MethodEndpoint methodEndpoint = (MethodEndpoint)endpoint;

        if(methodEndpoint != null && methodEndpoint.getBean().getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(getEndpointClass().getSimpleName()))
            {
            Assert.isInstanceOf(SoapMessage.class, messageContext.getResponse(),
                    "SimpleSoapExceptionResolver requires a SoapMessage");
            SoapMessage response = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
            String faultString = StringUtils.hasLength(ex.getMessage()) ? ex.getMessage() : ex.toString();
            SoapBody body = response.getSoapBody();
            SoapFault fault = body.addServerOrReceiverFault(faultString, getLocale());
            customizeFault(messageContext, endpoint, ex, fault);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Config**

```
<bean id="courseSectionExceptionResolver" class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisCourseSectionResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="1"></property>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="personExceptionResolver" class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisPersonResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="2"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="membershipExceptionResolver" class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisMembershipResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="3"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="bdemsExceptionResolver" class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisBdemsResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="4"></property>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="outcomeExceptionResolver" class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisOutcomeResolverInterceptor">
        <property name="order" value="5"></property>
    </bean>  

    <sws:interceptors>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0">
            <bean class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisCourseSectionResolverInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/pms2p0/wsdl11/sync/imspms_v2p0">
            <bean class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisPersonResolverInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/mms2p0/wsdl11/sync/imsmms_v2p0">
            <bean class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisMembershipResolverInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/bdems1p0/wsdl11/sync/imsbdems_v1p0">
            <bean class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisBdemsResolverInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/oms1p0/wsdl11/sync/imsoms_v1p0">
            <bean class="com.test.adapter.ws.resolvers.LisOutcomeResolverInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor">
            <property name="logRequest" value="true"/>
            <property name="logResponse" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </sws:interceptors>
```